# Typo3 switch to default domain

Tags: typo3

In typo3 in the list view I have added two url records. The first one (on top) is www.domain.com and the second one is domain.com. When you now go directly to domain.com the webpage is opened under that url. But I want it to switch to www.domain.com and then op the home page.

How is it possible in typo3 that the url is always switched to the top urls, www.domain.com in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this as such in .htaccess:

Then you either don't need the domain records at all in TYPO3 (if the installation only has one site/domain) or just the www one.

```
RewriteEngine On

# * FORCE WWW *
# -----------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That solution is quite robust and non-www-addresses never show up in google.

Be careful if you have running subdomains like something.example.com though, this might need an advanced .htaccess rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just edit the record for the non-default domain and set the field "Redirect To" and the status code for the redirect.

You may not see these fields initially, if so, either check the checkbox "Show secondary options (palettes)" at the bottom of the page, or click the small "more options" icon directly under the domain field.

If you have many domains, this becomes impractical. In that case, consider doing the redirect directly in the webserver configuration. That would also be more performant (as TYPO3 isn't even started up to do the redirect).